# Default java cacerts don't work

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, keystore

I've an SSL secured rest ws.

In my java client I've added the certificat to the cacerts store, but it work only if i set explicitly the cacerts file path in the javax.net.ssl.trustStore  parameter and the password in javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword.

the java home is set to :
java.home : C:\ide\jdk1.7.0_45\jre

and the two parameters are set to :

```
  Properties pp = System.getProperties();

  Set<Object> s = pp.keySet();

  for (Object object : s) {
      System.out.println(object + " : " + pp.get(object));
  }

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\ide\\jdk1.7.0_45\\jre\\bin\\cacerts");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "secret");
```

result:

```
  java.runtime.name : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 
  sun.boot.library.path : C:\ide\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin
  .....
  java.home : C:\ide\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
  .... other java parameters value
  WS called with success
```

execution with Exception:

```
  Properties pp = System.getProperties();

  Set<Object> s = pp.keySet();

  for (Object object : s) {
      System.out.println(object + " : " + pp.get(object));
  }

  //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\ide\\jdk1.7.0_45\\jre\\bin\\cacerts");
  //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "secret");
```

result :

```
java.runtime.name : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path : C:\ide\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin
.....
java.home : C:\ide\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
.... other java parameters value
Exception in thread "main" 
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.execute(ApacheHttpClient4Executor.java:182)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:39)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.execute(AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.java:40)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:443)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:677)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.post(ClientRequest.java:566)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Can you also explain what the actual issue is? Exception trace etc.  might be of help.

Comment: You must be executing with a different installation of Java. JAVA_HOME is only used by IDEs and the JDKS, not by the `java` command.

Comment: @Abhinav i've added the whole maon methode, and the result log in the console.

Comment: @EJP both the java.home and the call to System.setProperty with the cacerts file path are executed in eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that i used the wrong cacerts file path.

the default cacerts file in java is :

\jre\lib\security\cacerts